# How to use use log4net with Unity?

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, log4net

How can I use log4net with Unity3d so that log output goes to the editor console and is logged to file?  Unity doesn't seem to be able to use an App.config, so the configuration needs to be done in code, but how do I write to the unity console when using log4net?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First add a reference to the `log4net` dll in the Unity editor.  You can do this by placing the log4net dlls into the `Assets/Plugins` directory, or in a child directory of the `Assets/Plugins/` directory.

Once `log4net` is referenced, you now need to setup the appenders so that log4net knows how to actually start logging.  This is what I have for my configuration:

```
/// <summary>
///  Configure logging to write to Logs\EventLog.txt and the Unity console output.
/// </summary>
public static void ConfigureAllLogging()
{
  var patternLayout = new PatternLayout
                      {
                        ConversionPattern = "%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline"
                      };
  patternLayout.ActivateOptions();

  // setup the appender that writes to Log\EventLog.txt
  var fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender
                     {
                       AppendToFile = false,
                       File = @"Logs\EventLog.txt",
                       Layout = patternLayout,
                       MaxSizeRollBackups = 5,
                       MaximumFileSize = "1GB",
                       RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size,
                       StaticLogFileName = true
                     };
  fileAppender.ActivateOptions();

  var unityLogger = new UnityAppender
                    {
                      Layout = new PatternLayout()
                    };
  unityLogger.ActivateOptions();

  BasicConfigurator.Configure(unityLogger, fileAppender);
}
```

This sets up log4net for logging to `Logs\EventLog.txt` and to unity's console logging, via the `UnityAppender` class.  The `UnityAppender` class looks like so (I have it as a private inner class):

```
/// <summary> An appender which logs to the unity console. </summary>
private class UnityAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
  /// <inheritdoc />
  protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
  {
    string message = RenderLoggingEvent(loggingEvent);

    if (Level.Compare(loggingEvent.Level, Level.Error) >= 0)
    {
      // everything above or equal to error is an error
      Debug.LogError(message);
    }
    else if (Level.Compare(loggingEvent.Level, Level.Warn) >= 0)
    {
      // everything that is a warning up to error is logged as warning
      Debug.LogWarning(message);
    }
    else
    {
      // everything else we'll just log normally
      Debug.Log(message);
    }
  }
}
```

Then, be sure to call `ConfigureAllLogging()` somewhere where you know it will be called.  I have it set in a static constructors of one of my global MonoBehavoirs.

Comment: A nice working example. Do note that it is recommended to put DLLs in `Assets\Plugins` directory.

Comment: @NikolaMalešević Good point.  I updated the answer to point to `Assets\Plugins` instead.

Comment: Old post , wonder if it's still alive :)
You still need to use the log4net logger right like so , on each script that needs logging:
`code 
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);`


and then : 
`code 
log.Debug("this is my Debug message");
log.Error("this is my error message");
log.Fatal("this is my Fatal message");
log.Warn("this is my Warn message");`
 sorry couldn't get this to format correctly

Comment: This builds fine on windows but fails on Mac, giving "Extracting referenced dlls failed." message when API compatibility level is set to .NET 2.0 and "The Assembly System.Web is referenced by log4net" when set to .NET 2.0 Subset. Any ideas on how to get around?

Comment: @Gio are you building for Mac or for the web?

Comment: @MackieChan I was trying to build for Mac, but the issue was something completely different. I had downloaded newer build modules (I think 5.3.1) and tried to build using Unity 5.3.0. After I updated both Unity and build modules to the latest versions I was able to build again. Odd encounter. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: I have add log4net to my unity app using above code, it's work well but when take build and installed in another system log file is not created. What I am missing please suggest.